# Setting the height in percentage of a div

Tags: jquery, html, css, shopify

I have a website in which i need to set the dimensions of a div in following way :

```
width:86%;
height: 80%;
```

So that the div appears the correct size whenever the screen size is increased/decreased.

At the moment, width works fine, i can set the percentage of the width and the div resizes. However, the height does not, unless i specify the amount of pixels, but obviously, this does not work when the screen size changes. (Unless there is a way around this).

My question is that, why does the percentage for height not working in this div?

I have included some code below, i hope its enough to get a good ideas. Otherwise, the website is located here:

https://mimi-fasi.myshopify.com/ (the idea is to make the slider image in the middle fit that panel and the screen, so that there is no scrolling needed)

```
<div id="content">
 <div class="flexslider type-header scaled-text-base">
  <ul class="slides">
   <li class="slide slide-1 flex-active-slide" style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%; position: relative; opacity: 1; display: block; z-index: 2;">
  <a href="/collections/all">
  <img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0727/2709/t/2/assets/slide_1.jpg?155" alt="Slide 1" draggable="false">

  <div class="overlay-text posx-left posy-bottom"> 
    <div class="inner">

      <h1 class="text-1"><span class="scaled-text" style="font-size: 5.83333333333333%;">Welcome to</span></h1>
      <h2 class="text-2"><span class="scaled-text" style="font-size: 5.83333333333333%;">Masonry for Shopify</span></h2>

    </div>
  </div>

  </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#content {
max-width: 940px;
transition: padding 250ms;
overflow: hidden;
position: absolute;
left: 260px;
top: 100px;
}

.flexslider {
position: relative;
zoom: 1;
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
}

.flexslider .slides {
overflow: hidden;
zoom: 1;
margin: 0;
}
.slides, .flex-control-nav, .flex-direction-nav {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
}
```

If i set height:100%; within the HTML opening tag, it seems to work, except my navigation bar disappears and i cannot figure out how to get it back.

Comment: Can you please post your complete html? How did you define your body-tag? Have you 100% height on it?

Comment: body {
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 1.6em;
color: #5b6169;
background-color: #ffffff;
}

Answer (score 0):

Short answer ; div also should be in a container which should have a fixed-height( like 'height:integer**px**' or 'height:integer**%**')

Because width already has a fixed-width container which is the width of the browser, but height doesnt.

Comment: If i add height:100% to every single div (apart from the HTML div) still nothing happens. Once i add it to the HTML div, then it works, but my navigation disappears!

Comment: try to see the elements on Google Dev. Tools and see where the nav is.

Comment: The navigation stretches down the page, completely distorted.